# Is there any way out to return Custom objects or List of Custom objects from hooked procedure in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, c++-cli, hook, code-injection

I am hooking simple managed process and injecting a dynamic SPY DLL into theat process to collect information from it and needs to send this information to other processes as well.

For this purpose I am using one injector library which can send the message to managed process's main window procedure. I need to get the list of all controls as list which are inside that hooked processes. For that my hook procedure cannot return some "Object" except. Here's my injector Hook procedure code and caller to this hook procedure.

```
Object^ MessageHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    try
    {
        if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
        {
            if (pCW->message == WM_INVOKEREMOTE)
            {
                // NOTE: This libary is probably loaded by Windows using some "LoadFrom"
                // resembling approach when the hook is installed. Appearantly, this causes
                // the CLR to be unable to find it when deserializing (even though we are
                // actually executing it in this moment!), so we need to help it. See
                // http://discuss.develop.com/archives/wa.exe?A2=ind0303a&L=dotnet-clr&D=0&T=0&P=10291
                AppDomain^ currentDomain = AppDomain::CurrentDomain;
                currentDomain->AssemblyResolve += gcnew ResolveEventHandler(HelperClass::ResolveRequestMessageAssembly);
                RequestMessage^ msg = (RequestMessage^)Deserialize();
                currentDomain->AssemblyResolve -= gcnew ResolveEventHandler(HelperClass::ResolveRequestMessageAssembly);

                // We need the path, otherwise the assembly have to be in the search path for the application in which it is injected
                String^ assemblyFile = Path::Combine(Path::GetDirectoryName(Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->Location), msg->AssemblyFile);
                Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::LoadFrom(assemblyFile);

                Type^ type = assembly->GetType(msg->TypeName);

                Object^ retVal = type->InvokeMember(msg->MethodName, BindingFlags::Static | BindingFlags::Public | BindingFlags::InvokeMethod, nullptr, nullptr, msg->Args);
                //Serialize(retVal);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Object^ ex)
    {
        // No need to make a reference to System.Windows.Forms assembly just to show a
        // messagebox, we just need to make a string conversion
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(ex->ToString());
        LPCTSTR error = reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(ptr.ToPointer());
        ::MessageBox(NULL, error, L"InvokeRemote Failed", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        Serialize(nullptr);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

CALLER TO MessageHookProc

====================

```
Object^ Injector::InvokeRemote(IntPtr hWnd, String^ assemblyFile, String^ typeName, String^ methodName, array<Object^>^ args)
{
    RequestMessage^ msg = gcnew RequestMessage();
    msg->AssemblyFile = assemblyFile;
    msg->TypeName = typeName;
    msg->MethodName = methodName;
    msg->Args = args;
    ::Serialize(msg);

    HINSTANCE hinstDLL = LoadLibrary((LPCTSTR) _T("InjectLib.dll"));
    DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId((HWND)hWnd.ToPointer(), NULL);
    HOOKPROC procAddress = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "MessageHookProc");
    HHOOK messageHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, procAddress, hinstDLL, threadID);

    // This forces it to be loaded into the target adress space
    // CALLS ACTUALLY THE HOOK PROCEDURE BY SENDING MESSAGE TO MAIN WINDOW OF HOOKED PROCESSS.
    // ==========================================================================
    SendMessage((HWND)hWnd.ToPointer(), WM_INVOKEREMOTE, 0, 0);   

    ::UnhookWindowsHookEx(messageHookHandle);
    // Object^ retVal = Deserialize();
    return retVal;
}
```

So here I dont want objects to be serialized in this manner, they must be RETUNRED from hook procedure and this caller should then be able to transfer those objects to some other module or processs.

Regards
Usman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize the data into some encoding that doesn't use pointers, because those pointers have no meaning in any other process.  Then you can use any form of IPC, e.g. a named pipe, to transfer the encoded data to your other process.